# Ajax php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call on `txt_RollNo`'s `blur` event to bring `std_name`,`Class`,`age` from database and fill it in `txt_name`,`txt_class`,`txt_age`.

In a single call can I have `name`,`class`,`age` all as a whole in array or any, how to seperate it.

```
$("#txt_RollNo").blur(function(){   
$.ajax({
            url:'getSudent.php',
            data:'stdID='+ $(this).val().trim(),
            success:function(array_from_php)
            {
            //but here i m receiving php array, how deal in jquery
                //$("#txt_name").val(array_from_php);
                //$("#txt_Class").val(array_from_php);
                //$("#txt_age").val(array_from_php);

            }
            })   
});
```

---

getSudent.php  echos array as below

```
<?php   
  $qry=mysql_query("select * from students where studentID='".$_GET['std_ID']."'");   
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);   
  echo $row;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $qry=mysql_query("select * from v_shop where shop_no='".$_GET['shopno']."'");   
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);   
  echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

JavaScript

```
...
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
    success:function(array_from_php){
        console.log(array_from_php); // WTF is this?
```

See json_encode : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Make sure to add that you need `dataType: 'json'` in your AJAX call, and that `array_from_php` is now an object.

Comment: @Rocket the docs say: "dataType - Default: **Intelligent Guess** (xml, **json**, script, or html)" http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: That's only if you output your PHP as `Content-type: application/json`.  Otherwise, jQuery treats it as text.

Comment: @Rocket Are you sure about that? Don't get me wrong though, `dataType: 'json'` is def best practice with the correct PHP Content-type headers.

Comment: Yes.  If you don't add `header('Content-type: application/json')`, jQuery "intelligently guesses" that it's text.

Answer (score 3):

First in php send it as json:

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

then just treat it as any array:

```
$("#txt_RollNo").blur(function(){   
$.ajax({
        url:'getSudent.php',
        data:'stdID='+ $(this).val().trim(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success:function(array_from_php)
        {
           // i suggest you output the array to console so you can see it
           // more crearly
          console.log(array_from_php);
            $("#txt_name").val(array_from_php[0]);
            $("#txt_Class").val(array_from_php[1]);
            $("#txt_age").val(array_from_php[2]);

        }
        })   
});
```

Comment: It's not just gonna magically be an array.  You need to have PHP output it as such (`json_encode`).

Comment: Wouldn't `array_from_php.name` be better than `array_from_php[0]`?

Comment: thanx every 1 and stackoverflow.com